# Why is my machine learning model always predicting the same wrong answer even when prediction is already in my dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

The goal is for my Tensorflow machine learning model to predict the Type of any Beyblade preset combination. A Beyblade preset is made up of **4 parts** - Energy Ring, Fusion Wheel, Spin Track, Performance Tip. A Beyblade preset is only **named FusionWheel_EnergyRing_SpinTrack_PerformanceTip**, for example - "**Storm_Pegasus_105_RF**". Additionally, the Energy Ring, Fusion Wheel, and Performance Tip each have 3 stats - **Attack, Defense, Stamina**. The only value that is not generally known is the **Type** which is what this model is trying to predict for random given Beyblade preset combinations. **The four Types are Attack, Balance, Defense, Stamina**.

The data features being given to determine the Type of a new beyblade preset is first the 3 stats numbers for the Energy Ring, Fusion Wheel, and Performance Tip being `'Attack_EnergyRing', 'Defense_EnergyRing', 'Stamina_EnergyRing'` `'Attack_FusionWheel', 'Defense_FusionWheel', 'Stamina_FusionWheel'` `'Attack_PerformanceTip', 'Defense_PerformanceTip', 'Stamina_PerformanceTip'` secondly the string values for the Beyblade preset combination itself for the model to also consider for predicting type `'EnergyRing', 'FusionWheel', 'SpinTrack', 'PerformanceTip'` and finally the stat total numbers for each of the 3 stats, which are the sum of each stat Attack, Defense, and Stamina values of the FusionWheel, EnergyRing, and PerformanceTip being `'Attack_Total', 'Defense_Total', 'Stamina_Total'`.

**The problem is that the model always predicts Attack for any random Beyblade preset I put regardless of if it's wrong or not, even when I use a Beyblade preset that's already in my dataset.**

My dataset shows everything needed to be known about each Beyblade preset:

[Stats Dataset](https://github.com/RichardOseyamhen/BeybladeStatsDatasets/blob/main/BeybladeStatsDataset%232.csv)

I tried simple random Beyblade preset combinations expecting the model to predict one of the four Types. One random Beyblade preset combination I tried was **Earth_Virgo_T125_ES** which has Stamina Beyblade preset common parts (EnergyRing, FusionWheel, SpinTrack, and PerformanceTip values) in my dataset as well as Stamina centric stats and stat totals (Attack, Defense, Stamina stats and the total for each), which I expected to give me Stamina but it still ends up being wrongly predicted as Attack. I even tried using a Beyblade preset **already** in my dataset which I did in my code block example below, for example **Rock_Leone_145_WB** being stated as **Defense** in the dataset still ended up being predicted as **Attack**. All stats numbers I use in the pandas DataFrame are taken directly from my dataset as well.

Here is my code on what I'm doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

# Load the dataset
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RichardOseyamhen/BeybladeStatsDatasets/main/BeybladeStatsDataset%232.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)

# Extract features and labels
# Assuming the dataset columns are ordered as you listed
X = df[['Attack_EnergyRing', 'Defense_EnergyRing', 'Stamina_EnergyRing',
        'Attack_FusionWheel', 'Defense_FusionWheel', 'Stamina_FusionWheel',
        'Attack_PerformanceTip', 'Defense_PerformanceTip', 'Stamina_PerformanceTip',
        'EnergyRing', 'FusionWheel', 'SpinTrack', 'PerformanceTip']]

# Encode categorical labels
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(df['Type'])

# Include all numerical columns before one-hot encoding
numerical_columns = ['Attack_EnergyRing', 'Defense_EnergyRing', 'Stamina_EnergyRing',
                      'Attack_FusionWheel', 'Defense_FusionWheel', 'Stamina_FusionWheel',
                      'Attack_PerformanceTip', 'Defense_PerformanceTip', 'Stamina_PerformanceTip']

# Use OneHotEncoder for categorical features
categorical_features = ['EnergyRing', 'FusionWheel', 'SpinTrack', 'PerformanceTip']
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X_categorical_original = pd.DataFrame(onehot_encoder.fit_transform(X[categorical_features]).toarray())

# Ensure all column names are strings for the original dataset
X_categorical_original.columns = X_categorical_original.columns.astype(str)

# Concatenate the numerical and one-hot encoded categorical features for the original dataset
X_original = pd.concat([X[numerical_columns], X_categorical_original], axis=1)

# Ensure all column names are strings for the original dataset
X_original.columns = X_original.columns.astype(str)

# Now, include all numerical columns when fitting the scaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_original[numerical_columns])

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_original, y_encoded, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Ensure that the feature names in the test set match the feature names in the training set
X_test_original = X_test.copy()  # No need to modify the test set

# Standardize the feature values for the training and testing sets
X_train_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(X_train[numerical_columns]), columns=numerical_columns)
X_test_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(X_test_original[numerical_columns]), columns=numerical_columns)

# Build the model
num_classes = len(label_encoder.classes_)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train_scaled.shape[1],)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model with sparse categorical cross-entropy
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model with early stopping
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=250, validation_data=(X_test_scaled, y_test), callbacks=[early_stopping])

# Evaluate the model
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test_scaled, y_test)
print(f'Test Accuracy: {test_accuracy}')

# Make predictions for a new Beyblade preset
new_beyblade_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Attack_EnergyRing': 1,  # Replace with the actual values 
    'Defense_EnergyRing': 4,
    'Stamina_EnergyRing': 2,
    'Attack_FusionWheel': 1,
    'Defense_FusionWheel': 4,
    'Stamina_FusionWheel': 2,
    'Attack_PerformanceTip': 1,
    'Defense_PerformanceTip': 5,
    'Stamina_PerformanceTip': 1,
    'EnergyRing': 'Leone',  # Add the EnergyRing value
    'FusionWheel': 'Rock',  # Add the FusionWheel value
    'SpinTrack': '145',  # Add the SpinTrack value
    'PerformanceTip': 'WB'  # Add the PerformanceTip value
}, index=[0])

# Calculate totals for the new Beyblade data
new_beyblade_data['Attack_Total'] = new_beyblade_data['Attack_EnergyRing'] + new_beyblade_data['Attack_FusionWheel'] + new_beyblade_data['Attack_PerformanceTip']
new_beyblade_data['Defense_Total'] = new_beyblade_data['Defense_EnergyRing'] + new_beyblade_data['Defense_FusionWheel'] + new_beyblade_data['Defense_PerformanceTip']
new_beyblade_data['Stamina_Total'] = new_beyblade_data['Stamina_EnergyRing'] + new_beyblade_data['Stamina_FusionWheel'] + new_beyblade_data['Stamina_PerformanceTip']

# One-hot encode the categorical features for the new Beyblade data
new_beyblade_categorical = pd.DataFrame(onehot_encoder.transform(new_beyblade_data[['EnergyRing', 'FusionWheel', 'SpinTrack', 'PerformanceTip']]).toarray())

# Ensure all column names are strings for the new Beyblade data
new_beyblade_categorical.columns = new_beyblade_categorical.columns.astype(str)

# Concatenate the numerical and one-hot encoded categorical features for the new Beyblade data
new_beyblade_data_encoded = pd.concat([new_beyblade_data[numerical_columns], new_beyblade_categorical], axis=1)

# Transform the new Beyblade data using the fitted scaler
new_beyblade_data_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(new_beyblade_data_encoded[numerical_columns]), columns=numerical_columns)

# Make predictions for the new Beyblade preset
predictions = model.predict(new_beyblade_data_scaled)

# Decode the predicted label
predicted_label = label_encoder.inverse_transform([tf.argmax(predictions[0])])[0]

# Printing the totals
print(new_beyblade_data['Attack_Total'])
print(new_beyblade_data['Defense_Total'])
print(new_beyblade_data['Stamina_Total'])

# Print prediction
print(f'Predicted Beyblade Type: {predicted_label}')
```

Here is the Google colab link so you can test it out yourself and see where the problem may lie:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MXCI6Q7N1ruy8efGXiftYLj1FObqvjO_

Link to my dataset if needed:

[Stats Dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RichardOseyamhen/BeybladeStatsDatasets/main/BeybladeStatsDataset%232.csv)

Comment: In some contexts, a model can learn a rule like "always predict the majority class" if there is no pattern that it can learn. Do you if there is a pattern to which type a Beyblade has?

Comment: @NickODell Thanks for notifying me! It has now been made public.

Comment: @NickODell Pattern wise for the stats a lot of the time when a Beyblade preset has the highest Attack by a considerable amount, its considered an Attack type. Likewise for Defense, and Stamina types. Balance types are a bit different in the sense that at least 2 of the 3 stats or all 3 of the stats are close to each other numerically, for example 7 attack, 12 defense, 7 stamina or 9 attack, 9 defense 8 stamina. Patterns should also be found in the categorial features like the Energy Ring, Fusion Wheel, Spin Track, Performance Tip in which Type of Beyblade presets they have been most found in.

Comment: Looking at the results of your training, the loss is NaN. This is a bad sign. In your X variable, you have NaN values, which is subsequently causing the loss to be NaN. I would suggest finding a way to fill those NaN values. For example, the Beyblade Aquario_105_F has a NaN in the Attack_EnergyRing column.

Comment: @NickODell There is also NaN in some columns of the EnergyRing, FusionWheel, SpinTrack, and PerformanceTip because the specific Beyblade Preset combination doesn't have those. I know I could just fill the numerical NaN values with 0, but that leaves me wondering what I would do with the string NaN values/categorial features (EnergyRing, FusionWheel, SpinTrack, PerformanceTip) that may be NaN.

Comment: @NickODell Might I also add that in Jupyter Notebook the loss doesn't show as NaN and for example shows as loss: 1.3656 at the last epoch.

Comment: "but that leaves me wondering what I would do with the string NaN values/categorial features" Not clear to me you need to do anything about them. One hot encoding removes the NaN, doesn't it?

Comment: "Might I also add that in Jupyter Notebook the loss doesn't show as NaN and for example shows as loss" Which Jupyter notebook are you referring to? The colab? I have a jupyter notebook where I ran your code and it has a NaN loss.

Comment: @NickODell My localhost Jupyter notebook with pandas version being 2.1.4 shows no NaN loss. Meanwhile Google Colab Jupyter notebook pandas version is only 1.5.3 which as we know shows NaN loss. Want to move discussion to chat?

Comment: @NickODell I also have the latest version of those libraries.

Comment: Try to delete all rows with NaN values from dataset